# Update value with first_or_create in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a table 'Likes' with columns business_id, user_id and liked(0,1) and a function 'change_like_status'.

Now on every function call, If the value is 1 then set it to 0 (or vice versa) and if record doesn't exists then create one with value 1.

The first_or_create method is working just fine but how can i toggle value of column 'liked' while using this method?

Here is my function:

```
def change_like_status
  if current_user.present?
    status = Like.where("business_id = ? AND user_id = ?",params['id'],current_user.id).first_or_create(:business_id => params['id'],:user_id => current_user.id,:liked => '1')
    abort status.inspect
  else
    return render :json => {:status => false,:msg=>"You need to sign in before performing this action."}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In you controller, make the changes

```
def change_like_status
  if current_user
    status = Like.create_or_change_status(params[:id], current_user.id)
  else
    return render json: { status: false, msg: "You need to sign in before performing this action." }
  end
```

end

In your model `like.rb` file, add a method

```
def self.create_or_change_status(business_id, user_id)
   status = where(business_id: business_id, user_id: user_id).first
   if status.nil?
      status = create({business_id: business_id, user_id: user_id, liked: 1})
   else
      status.update_attributes(liked: !status.liked)
   end
   status
end
```

Comment: instead of update_attributes u can use update_column which won't call the callbacks and just writes to DB

Comment: @huanson, it changes depending on the requirements, whether I want the callbacks to work or no

Answer (score 1):

```
def change_like_status
  if current_user
    current_user.likes.find_by(business_id: params[:id]).switch_status!
  else
    return render json: { status: false, msg: "You need to sign in before performing this action." }
  end
end

class Like
  def switch_status!
    self.update_column :liked, !liked
  end
end
```

**other approach should be something like that**

```
class Like
  def switch_status!
    self.update_column :liked, !liked
  end
end


class User
  def likes id
    likes_for_business id
  end

  def likes_for_business(id)
    likes.find_by(business_id: id) || likes.create(:business_id: id, liked: true)
  end
end

# controller
current_user.likes(params[:id]).switch_status!
```

Comment: It gives me error: undefined method `find_by' for 1:Fixnum

Comment: whats the relation of likes ? what does current_user.likes return? should be an AR colleciton if its has_many likes?